# 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start running in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

The dreaded error has been plaguing me for days...

Running:

- .net core 5.0.409
- VS Professional 2019
- Windows 10

When running from command line (dotnet run {project}.csproj) everything runs just fine, but when running from Visual Studio on IIS Express I receive the 500.30.

No breakpoints are hit in startup or program.

Event log is unhelpful: "Application {name} hit unexpected managed exception, exception code = '0xe0434352'. Please check the stderr logs for more information."

I cannot for the life of me get stdout logging to work.

Nothing useful in the Output logs.

This works fine in VS on other machines.

Comment: maybe [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58397288/asp-net-core-3-and-500-30-in-process-startup-failure)?  Same http error and event log error

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite explain why this worked, but upgrading VS to 2022 sucessfully resolved the problem. However, one indication that led me to this solution is that the application was developed using 2022 and I was trying to run on 2019.